# unable to import function into anther script

Tags: python

Below is the user created function saved as functions.py

```
def commands():    

    if len(a) > len(b):

        print(list(set(a) - set(b)))

    else:

        print(list(set(b) - set(a)))

    return
```

And below is the script where i am trying to import function

```
import paramiko

from functions import commands

a = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']

b = ['aa', 'bb',]

print commands()
```

But I am getting an error

NameError: global name 'a' is not defined

Something is wrong in using the variable or function. Can someone help please ?

Comment: you need to read about "scope" in python, in short, there's no way for `commands` to know about `a` and `b` without passing them as parameters to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def commands(a,b):    

    if len(a) > len(b):

        print(list(set(a) - set(b)))

    else:

        print(list(set(b) - set(a)))

    return
```

and

```
import paramiko

from functions import commands

a = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']

b = ['aa', 'bb',]

commands(a,b)
```

You can't expect it to know the variables without passing them.

Comment: Below is the output

['cc', 'dd']

None

Why I am getting 'none' at the last ?

Comment: `commands(a,b)` returns None, and that is what you are printing with `print (commands())`. Look at my code. You don't need to print it.

Answer (score 1):

you should assign parameter before it's used and then call the function with passing parameter in it. like...

```
#function.py
def commands(a,b):
    if len(a) > len(b):
        print(list(set(a) - set(b)))
    else:
        print(list(set(b) - set(a)))
    return

#scripy.py

import paramiko

from functions import commands

a = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']

b = ['aa', 'bb',]

commands(a,b)
```

without passing parameter how your function can work??

Comment: stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command('show lldp neighbor interface' + " " + q[0] + " " + '| match add')

    z = stdout.read()

    A = z.split()

    A = A[9]

The above one is stored as function and output A wanted to use in another script. If i use getting below error "NameError: name 'A' is not defined" I tried using global A in function still the same.